# How to get Qt Enterprise Add-ons or Qt modules from the EnterpriseAddOns?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7-x64, qt5.7

I want to use `QtDataVisualization`. The following [installation guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-getting-started.html) says that

> The module can be found under Qt Enterprise Add-Ons in the package manager.
>
> ...
>
> The source code is installed into the QtDataVisualization folder under EnterpriseAddOns.

It seems that I can´t find the **Qt Enterprise Add-ons** in the *MaintenanceTool*. (I use this [Repo-Source](http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/) for the *MaintenanceTool*)

I installed [Qt 5.7.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2015, 924 MB)](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

How to get the **Qt Enterprise Add-ons** on Windows?

Is there another Repository to use or can I build it from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installer is fine. From Qt 5.7 Data Visualization is available for open source users:

> Previously commercial-only Qt Data Visualization module is now included in Qt under also GPLv3 license for open source users

Since you are using online installer, you need after downloading initial 18 Mb installer and launching it, make sure that you checked

```
Qt 5.7 -> Qt Data Visualization
```

checkbox in components you are installing. By default it is unchecked.